# Istio gRPC gateway accepts the call and responces but i can't get the responce

Tags: postman, openshift, grpc-java, istio-gateway, istio-sidecar

Good day to all! I'm having an issue with istio ingress configuration for gRPC service.
My istio config is following:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: test-grpc-gateway
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  selector:
    app:-grpc-gateway
    environment: test
  servers:
    - hosts:
        - test-grpc-gateway.apps.osh-cln01-test.eub.kz
      port:
        name: http2
        number: 80
        protocol: HTTP2
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: adapter-info-grpc
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  gateways:
    - test-grpc-gateway
  hosts:
    - '*'
  http:
    - match:
        - uri:
            prefix: /
      route:
        - destination:
            host: adapter-info.adapters.svc.cluster.local
            port:
              number: 10540
            subset: adapter-info-grpc
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: adapter-rsbk-info-grpc
  namespace: adapters
spec:
  host: adapter-info.adapters.svc.cluster.local
  subsets:
    - labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: adapter-info
        app.kubernetes.io/name: adapter-info
      name: adapter-info-grpc
  trafficPolicy:
    portLevelSettings:
      - loadBalancer:
          simple: ROUND_ROBIN
        port:
          number: 10540
```

I call the service using postman's grpc call and call the url 'test-grpc-gateway.apps.osh-cln01-test.eub.kz'. Reflector successfully pulls the methods of gRPC server but doesn't seem to recieve the server responses.

Logs of the gRPC server shows that server indeed received the call, processed it and sent a responce, but what I get in postman is 'Received RST_STREAM with code 0'.

Here're the logs:

```
2023-12-05T14:49:50.8062336+06:00 [INF] [0HMVLDSFKPKGC:00000001] (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics) Request starting HTTP/2 POST http://test-grpc-gateway.apps.osh-cln01-test.example.com/grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflection/ServerReflectionInfo application/grpc -
2023-12-05T14:49:50.8079935+06:00 [DBG] [0HMVLDSFKPKGC:00000001] (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher) 3 candidate(s) found for the request path '"/grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflection/ServerReflectionInfo"'
2023-12-05T14:49:50.8080435+06:00 [DBG] [0HMVLDSFKPKGC:00000001] (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher) Endpoint '"gRPC - /grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflection/ServerReflectionInfo"' with route pattern '"/grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflection/ServerReflectionInfo"' is valid for the request path '"/grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflection/ServerReflectionInfo"'
2023-12-05T14:49:50.8080710+06:00 [DBG] [0HMVLDSFKPKGC:00000001] (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher) Endpoint '"gRPC - Unimplemented method for grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflection"' with route pattern '"grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflection/{unimplementedMethod:grpcunimplemented}"' is valid for the request path '"/grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflection/ServerReflectionInfo"'
2023-12-05T14:49:50.8080886+06:00 [DBG] [0HMVLDSFKPKGC:00000001] (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher) Endpoint '"gRPC - Unimplemented service"' with route pattern '"{unimplementedService}/{unimplementedMethod:grpcunimplemented}"' is valid for the request path '"/grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflection/ServerReflectionInfo"'
2023-12-05T14:49:50.8081917+06:00 [DBG] [0HMVLDSFKPKGC:00000001] (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware) Request matched endpoint '"gRPC - /grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflection/ServerReflectionInfo"'
2023-12-05T14:49:50.8087639+06:00 [DBG] [0HMVLDSFKPKGC:00000001] (Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware) Static files was skipped as the request already matched an endpoint.
2023-12-05T14:49:50.8088214+06:00 [INF] [0HMVLDSFKPKGC:00000001] (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware) Executing endpoint '"gRPC - /grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflection/ServerReflectionInfo"'
2023-12-05T14:49:50.8209506+06:00 [DBG] [0HMVLDSFKPKGC:00000001] (Grpc.AspNetCore.Server.ServerCallHandler) Reading message.
2023-12-05T14:49:50.8210085+06:00 [DBG] [0HMVLDSFKPKGC:00000001] (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel) Connection id ""0HMVLDSFKPKGC"", Request id ""0HMVLDSFKPKGC:00000001"": started reading request body.
2023-12-05T14:49:50.8210705+06:00 [DBG] [0HMVLDSFKPKGC:00000001] (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel) Connection id ""0HMVLDSFKPKGC"", Request id ""0HMVLDSFKPKGC:00000001"": done reading request body.
2023-12-05T14:49:50.8246357+06:00 [DBG] [0HMVLDSFKPKGC:00000001] (Grpc.AspNetCore.Server.ServerCallHandler) Sending message.
2023-12-05T14:49:50.8254736+06:00 [DBG] [0HMVLDSFKPKGC:00000001] (Grpc.AspNetCore.Server.ServerCallHandler) Reading message.
2023-12-05T14:49:50.8257861+06:00 [INF] [0HMVLDSFKPKGC:00000001] (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware) Executed endpoint '"gRPC - /grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflection/ServerReflectionInfo"'
2023-12-05T14:49:50.8261282+06:00 [INF] [0HMVLDSFKPKGC:00000001] (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics) Request finished HTTP/2 POST http://test-grpc-gateway.apps.osh-cln01-test.example.com/grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflection/ServerReflectionInfo application/grpc - - 200 - application/grpc 19.8670ms
2023-12-05T14:4
```

Can anybody help?

I tried changing the gateway protocol to grpc and http but only http2 works. Just can't find a good docs on this. I don't know much about mTLS and gRPS requirements on TLS so probably that could be the case? Any help is highly appreciated.